# Using msgctl() function in the kernel space

Tags: kernel

in order to obtain the number of messages in a SysV queue from its ID I have used the function msgctl() in user space without any problem (as shown below):

```c
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int qid;
      struct msqid_ds qstatus;

      qid=(int)atoi(argv[1]);

      if(msgctl(qid,IPC_STAT,&qstatus)<0){
    perror("msgctl failed");
    exit(1);
      }

      printf("There are %d messages for queue with ID %d\n",qstatus.msg_qnum,qid);
    }
```

Now, I need to do the same thing in kernel space, but the code below doesn't work (the function return -1):

```c
    int get_num_from_id(int qid)
    {
    struct msqid_ds qstatus;

    sys_msgctl(qid,IPC_STAT,&qstatus);

    return qstatus.msg_qnum;
    }
```

Someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, it was the instruction "copy_to_user()" in the function "sys_msgctl()" of "msg.c": it obviously cannot work in kernel space correctly,  because the user space addressing is different; I have bypassed the problem by creating another function based on  "sys_msgctl()" that takes only "msqid" in input and returns the number of elements...  Exactly what I have need!

Thanks the same to everyone